# expand row based on integer in column and split into number of months between dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following dataframe:

| id | date_start | date_end | reporting_month | reporting_month_number | months_length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-31 23:56:22 | 2022-05-01 23:56:22 | 2022-03 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2022-03-31 23:48:48 | 2022-06-01 23:48:48 | 2022-03 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 2022-03-31 23:47:36 | 2022-08-01 23:47:36 | 2022-03 | 1 | 6 |

I would like to split each id row so I can have a row for each of the `months_length`, starting on the date of `reporting_month`, like this:

| id | date_start | date_end | reporting_month | reporting_month_number | months_length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-31 23:56:22 | 2022-05-01 23:56:22 | 2022-03 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-03-31 23:56:22 | 2022-05-01 23:56:22 | 2022-04 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-03-31 23:56:22 | 2022-05-01 23:56:22 | 2022-05 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 2022-03-31 23:48:48 | 2022-06-01 23:48:48 | 2022-03 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2022-03-31 23:48:48 | 2022-06-01 23:48:48 | 2022-03 | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 2022-03-31 23:48:48 | 2022-06-01 23:48:48 | 2022-04 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 2022-03-31 23:48:48 | 2022-06-01 23:48:48 | 2022-05 | 4 | 4 |
| 3 | 2022-03-31 23:47:36 | 2022-08-01 23:47:36 | 2022-03 | 1 | 6 |
| 3 | 2022-03-31 23:47:36 | 2022-08-01 23:47:36 | 2022-04 | 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 2022-03-31 23:47:36 | 2022-08-01 23:47:36 | 2022-05 | 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 2022-03-31 23:47:36 | 2022-08-01 23:47:36 | 2022-06 | 4 | 6 |
| 3 | 2022-03-31 23:47:36 | 2022-08-01 23:47:36 | 2022-07 | 5 | 6 |
| 3 | 2022-03-31 23:47:36 | 2022-08-01 23:47:36 | 2022-08 | 6 | 6 |

I have tried several approaches but I can't seem to reach my objective.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, please consider giving a simple way to instanciate your dataframes. e.g. with a dictionary and use `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(...)` so that people may help you without much effort on reproducing your dataframes !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is,

```
df= df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['months_length'])].reset_index(drop=True)
df['reporting_month_number'] = df.groupby('id')['reporting_month_number'].cumsum()
```

O/P:

```
    id           date_start             date_end reporting_month  \
0    1  2022-03-31 23:56:22  2022-05-01 23:56:22         2022-03   
1    1  2022-03-31 23:56:22  2022-05-01 23:56:22         2022-03   
2    1  2022-03-31 23:56:22  2022-05-01 23:56:22         2022-03   
3    2  2022-03-31 23:48:48  2022-06-01 23:48:48         2022-03   
4    2  2022-03-31 23:48:48  2022-06-01 23:48:48         2022-03   
5    2  2022-03-31 23:48:48  2022-06-01 23:48:48         2022-03   
6    2  2022-03-31 23:48:48  2022-06-01 23:48:48         2022-03   
7    3  2022-03-31 23:47:36  2022-08-01 23:47:36         2022-03   
8    3  2022-03-31 23:47:36  2022-08-01 23:47:36         2022-03   
9    3  2022-03-31 23:47:36  2022-08-01 23:47:36         2022-03   
10   3  2022-03-31 23:47:36  2022-08-01 23:47:36         2022-03   
11   3  2022-03-31 23:47:36  2022-08-01 23:47:36         2022-03   
12   3  2022-03-31 23:47:36  2022-08-01 23:47:36         2022-03   

    reporting_month_number  months_length  
0                        1              3  
1                        2              3  
2                        3              3  
3                        1              4  
4                        2              4  
5                        3              4  
6                        4              4  
7                        1              6  
8                        2              6  
9                        3              6  
10                       4              6  
11                       5              6  
12                       6              6
```

​
Explanation:

1. Repeat rows based on months_length
2. Update Reporing Month Number based on groupby 'id'